# Countdown timers and images in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, image, user-interface, xamarin.forms, countdowntimer

I have a question about countdown timers and images in Xamarin.Forms I am hoping you can help me with.

I have set up a timer which counts down from 5 to 0 and repeats at 0 with new text and image through a series. The issue I am having is that the image blinks with each count down number. I understand that the screen is refreshing but is there a way to stop the refresh of the image each second?

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            _countSeconds--;

            if (_countSeconds == 0)
            {
                ndx++;
                _countSeconds = 5;
            };

            if (ndx < DailyT.Count && ndx >= 0)
            {
                BindingContext = DailyT[ndx];
                MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(DailyT[ndx].ImageA, typeof(BGLongsword).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

                //ISSUE: Image blinks each count down second
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            CountLabel.Text = _countSeconds.ToString();

            return true;
        });
```

Comment: why are you resetting the BindingContext every time?  Are you even using data binding?  And you only need to update the image when the value of `ndx` changes.  You are updating it every time, which is what causes the flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need to update the image when `ndx` changes

```
        if (_countSeconds == 0)
        {
            ndx++;
            _countSeconds = 5;

            if (ndx < DailyT.Count && ndx >= 0)
            {
               MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(DailyT[ndx].ImageA, typeof(BGLongsword).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
            }
            else
            {
               return false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Perfect that did the trick. didnt realise I should embed the second If statement in the first too. Thanks Jason